# RoR: Moving code from view to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view-helpers

I'm trying to best understand how to use rail helpers together with haml views.

I have a view which originally contained this logic

```
=   fund_levels_last(i, @fund_level_count) ? ( link_to "add new level", ad, {class: 'button orange sm'} ) : ( link_to "remove", accounts_ad_fund_level_path(ad, fl.object.id), {:class => 'button orange sm', :method => :delete, :remote => true, :confirm => t('q.are_you_sure')} )
```

Wanting to keep the view as clean of code as possible, I have been trying to move this logic to the helper.

```
   def fund_levels_last(i, flcount)
     if i ==  flcount
       true
     else
       false
     end
   end

   def fund_levels_btn(i, flcount)
     if self.fund_levels_last(i, flcount)
       link_to "add new level", ad, {class: 'button orange sm'}
     else
       link_to "remove", accounts_ad_fund_level_path(ad, fl.object.id), {:class => 'button orange sm', :method => :delete, :remote => true, :confirm => t('q.are_you_sure')}
     end
   end
```

However, in the helper I don't have access to the variables and objects in the view (ad, object, fl etc).  I presume I could pass all those on to the helper methods, but somehow that seems too complicated and I have the feeling I'm heading down the wrong track here.  My single line of code in the view seems to end up being 15 lines of code in the helper...

What would the simplest method of moving this logic from the view to a helper be?

Comment: You can take a look at https://github.com/drapergem/draper ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code is simple enough, you may actually want a partial.  Then you can pass code/variables like so:

`<%= render :partial => 'funds/partial_view', :locals => { :var => variable } %>`

but if you need a helper, you will have to pass as parameters:

`def funds_helper(var)
  //do something interesting
end`

however, there is no reason to take all your logic out of the view, instead break it into partials:

in controller:
`@fund_level = fund_levels_last(i, @fund_level_count)`

in view:
`<%= @fund_level ? render :partial => 'funds/add_new_level' : render :partial => 'funds/remove_level' %>`

Then have your partial views have the correct view.

Comment: Thanks!!  Decided to do this as a partial, calling it with render "fund_level_form", f:f, ad:ad.  Seems to work brilliantly :)

Answer (score 3):

By the way, the method

```
def fund_levels_last(i, flcount)
  if i ==  flcount
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

could simply be :

```
def fund_levels_last(i, flcount)
  i ==  flcount
end
```

and also, methods that return boolean often ends with a `?` so it would become `def fund_levels_last?(i, flcount)`

Comment: Thanks!  Obviously this is a much more elegant and efficient code!

The original problem with moving the logic of the view to the helper remains, though.  I have tried to keep the link_to in the view and just return the link_to data from the helper, but that didn't seem to work either...